# Getting CommandLine of a process by passing process ID (PID) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Basically what I need is all strings in `CommandLine` of a Process by passing the `PID`

[image]

I tried both:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = 7272"
```

and

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "PID = 7272" |Where-Object { 
    (Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId).TotalProcessorTime -ne $null 
} |Select Name,ProcessId,CommandLine
```

In either ways I am not getting the `CommandLine` contents. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "In either ways I am not getting the CommandLine contents!" ? Do you get an empty Property ?

Comment: At first one yes! but on second command nothing at all

Comment: The notepad `PID` is unique to that instance, so there wouldn't be a need for a filter on the `TotalProcessorTime`. On that note, `CommandLine` is returned when using `Get-Process` as well so there isn't really a need for querying WMI with `Get-CIMInstance`. As for why you're command didn't work on the 2nd example, I believe you're after `ProcessID` and not `PID`: `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessID = 7272"`

Comment: What _do_ you get when you run these commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with PowerShell 7.1, there is a native way of doing this:

```
Get-Process -PID 7272 | Select Name,Id,CommandLine
```

If you want to get the process by name you can do this:

```
Get-Process ArcSOC | Select Name,Id,CommandLine
```

If you need backward compatibility to older version of PowerShell, take a look at how it was implemented in PowerShell 7.1:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blame/72608fb829881727f7d9b6295fb133613a30b6fe/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/TypeTable_Types_Ps1Xml.cs#L1145-L1153

Taking that same approach, under Windows you can do:

```
(Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = '7272'").CommandLine
```

or

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = '7272'" | Select Name,ProcessId,CommandLine
```

Comment: The first example is powershell 7 only.

Comment: @js2010 good call! I didn't realize that.  Had to look it up.  It was added in PowerShell 7.1 https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/12288

Comment: Hi Tolga, thanks for your reply and sorry for late reply (I was on vacation)  but I am still getting empty space under CommandLine column

Comment: Try using the second example with Get-CimInstance.  Also maybe this executable didn't start with a command line.  Try opening Task Manager, go to the Details tab, right-click on the column headers choose "Select Columns", then check Command Line to make sure your process is showing a Command Line

Comment: I tried all command you provided in the post and unfortunately none of them return anything under  commandLine column, and YES there is  a long string in Task Manager for this PID but not returning in PS